# Snippet of code provides an error message on first run, but will run perfectly the second time without making any changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a snippet of code in my program that won't run the first time round. If I run it a second time without changing anything it runs, but never on the first time.

Here is the code that I am trying to run.

```
i = 0
x = len(df.index)

while i <= x-1:
    name = df.iloc[i,0]
    if name[0] == '0':
        df = df.drop(df.index[i], axis=0)
    else:
        i += 1
```

This is then the error message that comes up the first time.

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I understand what the error message is saying, but I also don't believe that is the issue because otherwise it wouldn't run the second time without any changes.

I have also tried copying and pasting my whole program into a new Jupyter notebook and get exactly the same error. Anyone have any ideas?

Update: I've solved the problem. I added in another variable n to take away from the total when a row was deleted. I'll add the updated code below if anyone else ever has the same issue.

```
i = 0
n = 0
x = len(df.index)

while i <= x-1-n:
    name = df.iloc[i,0]
    if name[0] == '0':
        df = df.drop(df.index[i], axis=0)
        n += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: It might be because the data frame might have changed in such a way that you do not get an error

Comment: You drop several rows during the loop, then try to iterate to the original length.  But the error doesn't happen until past the end of your filter, and you've modified the data by filtering what you want to filter.  So next time, you don't drop any, so the original length is still valid.

Comment: Is there anyway I can change the code to stop this happening? I want the program to be able to run automatically in the background, but not sure how to stop this happening.